# Nonexisting Oracle Database Constraint Violated

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I have been assigned to work on an application that has two tables, let's call them `MY_TABLE_ONE` and `MY_TABLE_TWO`. When a user enters data in a form, the data is entered into `MY_TABLE_ONE`. After this is completed, a database package is triggered, which essentially does the following:

```
DELETE FROM MY_TABLE_TWO;

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_TWO
mto.COLUMN_ONE,
moto.COLUMN_TWO,
mott.COLUMN_THREE
FROM MY_TABLE_ONE mto, MY_OTHER_TABLE_ONE moto, MY_OTHER_TABLE_TWO mott
WHERE mto.OTHER_TABLE_ONE_UUID = moto.UUID
AND mto.OTHER_TABLE_TWO_UUID = mott.UUID;
```

For some reason, this package began failing on the insert with a message of:

```
ORA-00001: unique constraint
(MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE_TWO_UK01) violated
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE", line 2
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Looking up the constraints on `MY_TABLE_TWO`, there is no `MY_TABLE_TWO_UK01` constraint. There is however a `MY_TABLE_TWO_UK` constraint which requires the 3 inserted columns to be unique. However, if I run the following query:

```
SELECT mto.COLUMN_ONE, moto.COLUMN_TWO, mott.COLUMN_THREE, COUNT(*) AS COUNTER
FROM MY_TABLE_ONE mto, MY_OTHER_TABLE_ONE moto, MY_OTHER_TABLE_TWO mott
WHERE mto.OTHER_TABLE_ONE_UUID = moto.UUID
AND mto.OTHER_TABLE_TWO_UUID = mott.UUID
GROUP BY mto.COLUMN_ONE, moto.COLUMN_TWO, mott.COLUMN_THREE
ORDER BY COUNTER DESC;
```

then all of the counts are 1. So it doesn't look like that constraint is being violated.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? I am not sure where that `01` is coming from for the constraint name. And I can't find where the constraint is violated.

Comment: your 
check won't tell you anything as obviously the counts are 1 as the duplicate data is not being inserted, due to the constraint

Comment: @SamHolder But I am pulling from `MY_TABLE_ONE`. I am looking for duplicates there that are throwing the error when you try to insert them into `MY_TABLE_TWO`. A count of 2 or more would show the constraint violating rows.

Comment: If only Oracle bothered to say in the error message something like 'unique index constraint violated'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it's an index

```
select * from all_ind_columns where index_name = 'MY_TABLE_TWO_UK01';
```

Comment: That index does appear to exist (I used the Toad UI, not the SQL you gave which returned nothing). It appears is connected to 3 other columns. However, the grouping using those 3 columns still yields only 1 counts. Any idea what's being violated about the index?

Comment: Ah, scratch that. Missed deleting a column in my script. Thanks for the help. The count script now yields a 2, indicating the issue. I'll investigate.

Comment: Spent almost 2 days, debugging this issue. Thanks a lot. i was performing bulk insert and wasn't able to figure out whats wrong with the data. Had no clue it would be an index.